# Beginner guide to test AngularJS controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

Can someone please point me to a resource, where I can get a Beginner tutorial on how to write unit test for AngularJS controller?

I have never written any test for JavaScript before. But, very experienced with jUnit test in core java.

I have found tons of resources over internet talking about testing JavaScript, but most of them pre-assume that I have done some javascript testing before or I am an expert on some javascript testing API.

For instance:

I didn't find [this](http://blog.freeside.co/post/41774841006/getting-started-with-angular-unit-tests) useful, couldn't run any test. Don't know from where to download angular-mocks.js and what is coffescript. I was thinking we just need to have [Jasmine JS](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/#section-It’s_Just_Functions) to test an angularJS controller.

And [Running AngularJS Test](http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/contribute) runs fine locally and is very detailed, but don't know how to test my simple controller using any of it.

Similarly I have gone through many such less than helpful (for me) tutorial and didn't go anywhere.

To make this question further specific. Suppose I have a controller like below

```
app.controller('abcController', function ($scope, $log, abcFactory {
    init();

    function init() {
        $scope.testVar="this is a test"
        }
    });
```

I just want to test if $scope.testVar value is set to "This is a test" or not. That is it!!

How to do that. Please don't write snippet of code, if possible please walk me through how to set all the files to get this test setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with Jasmin, I have created a plunk to illustrate how it works, I think after you will get it. [My link](http://plnkr.co/edit/YcymdEcOEOVkB89yzHdD) Really what you need is correctly bootstrap Jasmin.